# Wait until Ext.Ajax.request responds with success before setting variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, extjs, asynchronous

Below you will see some code to set the currently logged in user for an extjs 4 application.  If I have the alert uncommented, the code seems to wait until the alert is accepted before the code continues (it seems).  That allows enough time for the asynchronous call to complete with a success.  If I comment out the alert, the variable "employeeFilter" never gets set because the AJAX call didn't come back in time.  In which case, it sets the "employeeFilter" to null instead.  How can I fix this so it waits until the AJAX response comes back in success?

```
var loggedInUserId = null;
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/Controls/UserList/UserService.asmx/GetLoggedInUserId',
    method: 'POST',
    jsonData: { 'x': 'x' },
    success: function (response, opt) {
        loggedInUserId = Ext.decode(response.responseText).d;
    },
    failure: function (response) {
    }
});

//alert(loggedInUserId);
var employeeFilter = loggedInUserId;
var projectFilter = '-1';
```

Comment: Sounds like you should be assigning the `employeeFilter` value in your callback function.

Comment: the "A" in AJAX is for "asynchronous"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have done this.

```
var employeeFilter;        
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/Controls/UserList/UserService.asmx/GetLoggedInUserId',
    method: 'POST',
    jsonData: { 'x': 'x' },
    success: function (response, opt) {
        employeeFilter = Ext.decode(response.responseText).d;
        //Do here whatever you need to do once the employeeFilter is set. probably call a function and pass the employee filter as parameter. 
    },
    failure: function (response) {
    }
});

var projectFilter = '-1';
```

Comment: I have about 50 lines of code (that's used more than once), so I'd rather not perform everything in there

Comment: Wrap the 50 lines of code into a function and call the function right after you set the employeefilter in the ajax success call.